# Angular2 Notifications chaining with router navigate

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have a simple application form which on submit navigates to another page. 
I want to display a success message on clicking the submit button.

The below code works but after submit, it immeidately redirects to other page which shows the notifications for only a second. 
I cannot add the notificaiton to the destination page as it has multiple entry points.

```
onSubmit(form) {
this._service.success('Test', 'Test');  // this is from angular2-notificaitons library 
this.apartmentService.postRequests(this.data).then(_=>this.router.navigate(['Requests']));   //navigates to requests page which has multiple entry points
this.data = {};
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Comment: I don't know the notifications library. How does it allow to get notified when it the notification is closed or when it is hidden automatically? What does `this._service.success('Test', 'Test');` return?

Comment: I am using this documentation from the library https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications/blob/master/docs/toastNotifications.md

Comment: Can you please check if `this._service.getEmitter().subscribe(event => console.log('event', event))` emits any event that can be used to get notified about the notification being removed?

Comment: The property does not exist.. `error TS2339: Property 'getEmitter' does not exist on type 'NotificationsService'.`

Comment: Sorry, should be `getChangeEmitter()` https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications/blob/232e87a4ab9ea454d12fa3f6bde6b97f64289322/src/notifications.service.ts#L14

Comment: I think this is what you need: http://learnangular2.com/events/

Comment: can't find this one either .. `error TS2339: Property 'getChangeEmitter' does not exist on type 'NotificationsService'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you register the provider for the NotificationsService. I think the problem is that you're not registering it at the root of the application.

Try to move the NotificationsService and the SimpleNotificationsComponent directive to your app.component.

```
   @Component({
        selector: "app",
        directives: [SimpleNotificationsComponent],
        providers: [NotificationsService, PushNotificationsService],
        template: `
           <simple-notifications [options]="options" (onCreate)="onCreate($event)" (onDestroy)="onDestroy($event)">
           </simple-notifications>
        `
   })
```

Comment: I registered it in the component where I'll be using the notification. It works fine, it's just that the way the chaining redirects it to another component which doesn't have this service.

Comment: That's the problem. You should register it in a top level component so that the component you're navigating to knows about the notification.